# How to create a dynamic menu WPF MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Could please anyone explain how to create a Dynamic menu in WPF (using MVVM)?
Firstly I show three buttons with Devices in the half of the screen (Camera, Boiler, Sensor).
The App has special commands for each button.
For instance, if I press a Camera button - I get a Camera screen displayed in the second part of the screen. If I press a Boiler button - I get a Boiler screen displayed instead of Camera screen.

I have already done it, but for each device I did it individually in my XAML.

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button Content="Camera"
            Command="{Binding NavigationCameraCommand}"
            Margin="5"
            Height="30"/>
     <Button Content="Boiler".../>
</StackPanel>

<ContentControl Grid.Column="1"  Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}">
    <ContentControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:CameraViewModel}">
            <views:CameraView/>
        </DataTemplate>
             ...
 </ContentControl>
```

But If I add a new Device, I have to rewrite the code in the Main Form and because of that I want to do it dynamically. I created collection of devices in a Main View Model and try to use this collection in XAML.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Devices}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="{Binding Path=Name}"
                    Command="{?}}}"
                    Margin="5" Height="30"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

However I don't know how to bind a command to buttons. I have three commands in my Main View Model (OpenCameraScreenCommand, OpenBoilerScreenCommand, OpenSensorScreenCommand), it worked without any problems in static menu, but I don't know how to use it in Dynamic menu...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There a few ways to approach this, but the most "MVVM" way is probably to create a DeviceViewModel that would wrap your Device class and have an OpenCommand.  Then instead of binding to a collection of Devices, you would bind to a collection of DeviceViewModels.

The DeviceViewModel would be something like:

```
public class DeviceViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private _device;

    public Device Device
    {
        get { return _device; }
        set
        {
            _device = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Device");
        }
    }

    public ICommand OpenScreenCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand(OpenScreen, CanOpenScreen)
        }
    }

    private void OpenScreen(object param)
    {
        // open screen here
    }

    private bool CanOpenScreen(object param)
    {
        return true; // or whatever conditions you have...
    }
}
```

and your Xaml would look like the following:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding DeviceViewModels}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="{Binding Path=Device.Name}"
                    Command="{Binding Path=OpenScreenCommand}"
                    Margin="5" Height="30"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```